# Firebase send http cloud messaging from android app

Tags: android, firebase, android-volley

I am currently sending firebase cloud messages from Postman, using an http post request. Its all working fine. I am now trying to make a simple Android app to send the messages from, . However it doesn't work and I get either **InvalidRegistration** or **MissingRegistration** or **com.android.volley.AuthFailureError**

In postman, I do an http post request to https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

With 2 headers:

```
Key: 'Authorization'   Value: 'key=AAAAnfdQ2jM:AP....'

Key: 'Content-Type'     Value: application/json
```

Then in body, using raw:

```
{
"to": "/topics/anytopic",


"data": {
    "my_message": "Hi everyone!",
   }

}
```

Where and how do I put this information in my volley http post request?

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,"https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send", new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Response: " + response);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            return params;
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            return params;
        }
    };
    queue.add(sr);
```

I can't find any example of this.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a JSON body like this:

```
        JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
    jsonBody.put("to", REUVEN_TOKEN_BE_YOUNG);

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    jsonObject.put("my_message", "Keep eating healthy!");

    jsonBody.putOpt("data", jsonObject);


    final String requestBody = jsonBody.toString();


    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,"https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send", new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Response: " + response);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d(TAG, "That didn't work..." + error);
        }
    }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

            return params;
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("Authorization",BE_YOUNG_APP_KEY);

            return params;
        }



        @Override
        public String getBodyContentType() {
            return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        }

        @Override
        public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
            try {
                return requestBody == null ? null : requestBody.getBytes("utf-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                VolleyLog.wtf("Unsupported Encoding while trying to get the bytes of %s using %s", requestBody, "utf-8");
                return null;
            }
        }

    };
    queue.add(sr);
```